# Why can't I successfully follow the Argo CD Getting Started guide?

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-delivery, cicd, k3s, argocd

I have tried so many times uninstalling ArgoCD and reinstalling. I have no idea what I am doing wrong honestly.

I start by installing ArgoCD. I am not interested in anything fancy, so I'm trying the core installation.

```
kubectl create namespace argocd
kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/core-install.yaml
```

No errors. The guide says I can use argocd login --core to skip steps 3-5, so I do that:

```
cis@sd2:~$ argocd login --core
Context 'kubernetes' updated
```

Looks good as far as I know. Now I try to create their example application:

```
argocd app create guestbook --repo https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps.git --path guestbook --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace default
```

... Nothing. Nothing at all happens. I'm never prompted for another command as long as I don't interrupt the process by pressing control+c. Am I vastly misunderstanding the getting started guide? I am happy to provide any necessary information about my cluster, I just have no idea what information would even be relevant.

This is the guide I am trying to follow: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/

Comment: How are you accessing the service? port-forward?

Comment: @jordanm Hi. I am just trying to do what the guide tells me to do, which for core installation does not seem to include port forwarding.

Comment: The url `https://kubernetes.default.svc` is only valid *inside* the cluster. Where are you running this command?

Comment: Step 3 in the guide to which you've linked describes multiple scenarios for providing external access (including port forwarding). https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/#3-access-the-argo-cd-api-server

Comment: @larsks I honestly don't know how to answer your question. I am secure shelled into my remote server which is hosting my Kubernetes master plane and running these commands in that shell. Am I supposed to be running these commands "Inside" the Kubernetes cluster? If so how?

Comment: You should be running the commands from your PC with a proxy, port-forward, or other way to access the argo service inside the cluster. The getting started guide lists 3 options

Comment: @jordanm Ok, If I assume the way I would like to do it (via argocd login --core, skipping steps 3-5 as the guide says) will never work for some valid reason, I then should still be able to follow the rest of the guide to expose the service and login. I chose to expose it by turning the argocd-server service into a load balancer. However, then the following happens:

cis@sd2:~$ argocd login localhost --insecure
FATA[0000] Get "https://134.88.13.237:6443/api/v1/namespaces/argocd/pods?labelSelector=app.kubernetes.io%2Fname%3Dargocd-server": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Comment: Which version of kubernetes dud you used and how did you set up your cluster? Did you use bare metal or some cloud provider?

Comment: @kkopczak I am using k3s version v1.22.5+k3s1 on bare metal (3 linux servers).